# What technologies should I use to load content into a dynamic div?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an interesting project in mind, and I have a question.  You can see the look from my jank design below:[image]

I have a variety of technologies I'm planning on leveraging.  To give you an idea:

- node.js (for various servers)
- WebSockets (for chat client and some content I'd rather not disclose)
- canvas (for part of the `#content`)

Now, with this in mind, I have no problem leveraging technologies that are not supported by most browsers.  That's not any concern.

For my question, on the page I have laid out above, the only thing I want to change (besides the updating chat feature) is the content.  I would like to load the "Home", "About", "Contact" and "Login" sections of my website into the `#content` portion of the page.

Now, I have an instinct to say the best way to achieve this goal is through AJAX, but I'm not sure.  Since I could possibly just set up some files with the HTML I'd like to display, and then onclick, load them into the `#content` section.

Is this the best method to use?  I'm looking for practicality and performance.

Sorry for the bizarre question.

Thanks!

Comment: Wish you would've waited a little bit before selecting an answer. Rather than just suggest something, I took some time to create a fully-functioning demo for you.

Comment: Hey, now.  Although I don't want to take away my selection, I appreciate the example and suggestion a lot.  Also, although your answer is great, I think I still would have picked Eli's answer, as I would rather go through the motions myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to load these sections dynamically, ajax is the only way to go. I would definitely check out using a JavaScript library to handle the internals of making ajax calls for you, as writing this part from scratch can be difficult to do in a cross-browser manner. I would highly recommend jQuery for this: http://jquery.com/

I saw you mentioned WebSockets. WebSockets can be good for offloading some intensive JS processing, but it cannot be used for interacting with the DOM (e.g. accessing HTML elements, changing their content, getting form values, etc.).

Comment: Alright, cool.  I only mentioned WebSockets to give you an idea of what else I would be leveraging, just in case it could be of use.  I'm mainly going to be using it for the chat portion.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can decide not to have to learn AJAX, or deal with external Comet libraries, and use something like [NOLOH](http://www.noloh.com) which takes care of all these plumbing issues for you allowing you to focus on your application. For example, I took the liberty to create an actual NOLOH application based on your mockup design, which automatically uses AJAX for the content, and uses NOLOH's built in Comet support for the chat.

Click here for functioning example: http://www.noloh.com/Demos/StackOverflow1

As you can see from the very basic code (all of the code) posted below, and on [github here](https://github.com/noloh/StackOverflow-Answer--Basic-Site-Example), you simply lay out your objects, and tell them what you would like to do. NOLOH takes care of the rest, and handles all cross browser issues, client-server issues, and most other things you can imagine.

NOTE: This is only one of many ways to approach it, I could've used different layout types, more concise syntax, class variables instead of locals and external CSS, but I felt a simple approach would make things clearer. Also, sorry for using the unwieldy Yahoo URL as it was the most readily available.

```
require_once('/NOLOH/NOLOH.php');

class StackOverflowExample extends WebPage
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::WebPage('StackOverflow 5672167');
        $nav = new Panel(0, 0, 600, 30);
        $chat = new Panel(0, $nav->Bottom, 200, 500);
        $content = new MarkupRegion('', $chat->Right, $chat->Top, 400, 350);
        $rooms = new Panel($content->Left, $content->Bottom, 400, 150);
        $footer = new Panel(0, $chat->Bottom, 600, 50);

        $chat->BackColor = Color::LightGreen;
        $content->BackColor = Color::Yellow;
        $rooms->BackColor = Color::Orange;
        $footer->BackColor = Color::Gray;

        $this->Controls->AddRange($nav, $chat, $content, $rooms, $footer);

        $sections = array('HOME', 'ABOUT', 'CONTACT', 'LOGIN');

        foreach($sections as $section)
            $nav->Controls->Add(new Link(null, $section, 0, 5))
                ->Click = new ServerEvent($this, 'LoadSection', $content, $section);

        $nav->Controls->AllCSSMarginRight = '5px';
        $nav->Controls->AllLayout = Layout::Relative;
        $nav->CSSTextAlign = 'right';

        //Comet (Listener), Bind to Yahoo Flickr API through YQL
        $this->Controls->Add($listener = new Listener(
            'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20source%20from%20flickr.photos.sizes%20WHERE%20photo_id%20in%20(select%20id%20from%20flickr.photos.recent)%20and%20label%3D%22Thumbnail%22',
            new ServerEvent($this, 'LoadImage', $chat)));

        //Default Section
        $this->LoadSection($content, URL::GetToken('section', 'HOME'));
    }
    function LoadSection($contentPanel, $section)
    {
        $section = strtolower($section);
        if(file_exists($file = 'Content/' . $section))
        {
            $contentPanel->Text = file_get_contents($file);
            URL::SetToken('section', $section);
        }
    }
    function LoadImage($chat)
    {
        foreach(simplexml_load_string(Listener::$Data)->results->size as $photo)
        {
            $url = $photo['source'];
            $chat->Controls->Add($image = new Image((string)$url, rand(0, $chat->Width), rand(0, 200), 100, 100));
            Animate::Top($image, $chat->Height - $image->Height, 3000);
            Animate::Opacity($image, Animate::Oblivion, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the NOLOH [NavHandler](https://github.com/noloh/navhandler) Nodule, so that your content is bookmarkable without you having to worry about implementing the very basic NOLOH [Token functions](http://dev.noloh.com/#/articles/Bookmarks-and-NOLOH/), which I took the liberty to add here (URL::GetToken), so that the app is bookmarkable.

You're free to sign-up for a free NOLOH sandbox, and copy the code into your sandbox and play around with it. One way would be to change the MarkupRegion to an EditRegion so you have automatic edit-in-place capabilities.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of NOLOH

Comment: Lols, I like that disclaimer.  Thanks for the example, I may give it a try, but I'm kind of looking to learn some of this myself.  Thanks though!

Comment: Seems odd to me that you consider using something like jQuery as "doing it yourself", versus in NOLOH where it's "not doing it yourself", both NOLOH and jQuery abstract things out for you, it's odd to me why choosing one stack that does less for you and forces you to worry about more is better than using another technology that further takes care of things for you, as in my example above. It's not as if you want to get down to the very basics and write your own jQuery, I just find it very odd that your thought process considers jQuery more native than NOLOH, in fact it's less. Just odd.

Comment: That makes no sense.  Although jQuery abstracts true JavaScript.  It is possible to use pure JavaScript within jQuery.  In fact, I'm currently only using jQuery to use a `(document).ready()` event, as well as standardized `click` handlers.  I haven't taken the time to learn more about NOLOH yet, so I don't want to make any judgements off of something I have no familiarity with, but it appears like you're just a little sore because I didn't pick your answer.  Isn't choosing a stack a subjective decision?  Shouldn't it be based on what one wishes to accomplish and why?

Comment: I'm sorry if response sounded negative, it wasn't meant to. In fact, you can use JavaScript within NOLOH really nicely, as is demonstrated by this video here: http://www.youtube.com/phpframework#p/c/C102458C2FFD8ACF/6/fkmepX5fjEE, but that's not the issue I was referring to. It just didn't sit right with me that you said "looking to learn some of this myself", since in fact in any situation you wouldn't really be doing anything truly yourself. Perhaps I'm being too semantical, in any case, so long as you're happy it's fine. Hopefully the above completely functioning example + code helped.

Comment: I understand.  I probably interpreted you wrong.  I think I ASSumed (haha, get it? xD) too much without knowing the facts.  Either way, I'm glad you brought up NOLOH as I'll look into it some more.